# Codeigniter 404_override not working in routes

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try almost everything for fixed my problem but I can't

This is my routes file in codeigniter.

```
$route['default_controller']      = "main";
$route['404_override']            = 'my_error_page';
$route['(:any)'] = 'page/index/$1/';
```

My website working well normally but 404_override not redirect to my_error_page.
I see standart codeigniter 404 page like the picture

[image]

When I delete last line like following;

```
$route['default_controller']      = "main";
$route['404_override']            = 'my_error_page';
```

404_override redirect to my error page and of course web site not running well.

It is maybe a simple problem but I am confused.

Sorry bad english.
Please help.
Thaank you.

Comment: I has forgot the my page.php file,
The problem is solved. It is my mistake.

Comment: Read this, http://404-page-codeigniter.blogspot.in/